# VBA JSON PUT request with concatenation

Tags: json, vba

This is how I am constructing my JSON array to be sent via the PUT method where I am taking some cell value from excel:

```
body = "{""note"":""" & Cells(RowNote, 3).Value & """,""uniqueIdentifier:""" & Cells(RowNote, 2).Value & ",""IdentifierType"":""ACCOUNT_ID"",""CustomerId"":" & userID & "}"
```

However i got an error 13 mismatch.

This is an example of the JSON string that can be PUT correctly:

```
{"note":"call again", "uniqueIdentifier":1716, IdentifierType":"ACCOUNT_ID", "CustomerId":927560}
```

What should be corrected within the brackets?

Comment: just a suggestion: exchange the inner quotation marks with apostrophes, still a valid JSON but easier on the eyes. eg: `body = "{'note':'" & Cells(RowNote, 3).Value & "','uniqueIdentifier':'" & Cells(RowNote, 2).Value & "',"'IdentifierType':'ACCOUNT_ID','CustomerId':" & userID & "}"` and now you can notice that you have missed one right after the `uniqueIdentifier` in your code

Comment: @Banana haha I did that but part of it is showing as green comments!

Comment: good, it means that you did something wrong. you've missed a quotation mark around where your code turns to comments.

Comment: Ok ill test it further and update you accordingly

Comment: try `body = "{""note"":""" & Cells(RowNote, 3).Value & """,""uniqueIdentifier"":""" & Cells(RowNote, 2).Value & """,""IdentifierType"":""ACCOUNT_ID"",""CustomerId"":""" & userID & """}"`

Comment: and this `body = "{""note"":""" & Cells(RowNote, 3).Value & """,""uniqueIdentifier"":" & Cells(RowNote, 2).Value & ",""IdentifierType"":""ACCOUNT_ID"",""CustomerId"":" & UserId & "}"` if you do not want `"` around your integers

Comment: @Arul yes this last one worked perfectly. Kindly if you can post it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `body = "{""note"":""" & Cells(RowNote, 3).Value & """,""uniqueIdentifier"":" & Cells(RowNote, 2).Value & ",""IdentifierType"":""ACCOUNT_ID"",""CustomerId"":" & UserId & "}"` if you do not want `"` around your integers.